# How do i split an excel sheet into 3 sheets according to a column (UiPath)?

Tags: uipath, excel-2019

I have an Excel file  that I need to split into multiple .csv files based on the "Name" column, so that each file is like .csv using UiPath. I'm extracting the data to a data table, but I can't split them into different files by "Name".

[image: see image of table]

Answer (score 0):

You could use "filter data table" (https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/filter-data-table) to split the input data table into different output datatable.
Than you can write the output datatable in on other file o same file (but in different sheet).